# Extruding in Blender

Tags: modeling, rendering, extrude

1. I want to extrude one face of cube keeping one edge fixed.
2. I had to cut the 3d model. I am using knife tool for this. Is this the correct way?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Please read: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/1098/1853

Answer (score 1):

To extrude you can use 'E' key. Or open Mesh options on the viewport Menu. You can see there all options like Alt+E

To cut, the same, there are many options, and one I used to use is the Ctrl+R to cut the loop.

---